# Read MYSQL db in RapidMiner

Tags: mysql, jvm, environment-variables, rapidminer

I'm attempting to use the 'Read Database' operator in RapidMiner 5 to read an 'ExampleSet' from a Mysql database. I seem to establish a working connection with my db as I notice the Manage Database Connections window displays a 'Connection ok' message when prompted.

However when I attempt to run the 'Read Database' process I receive the following error

"Process failed:
Failed to lookup .javax.naming.NoInitialContextException:
Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter,
or in an application resouce file:
java.naming.factory.initial"

I don't know how to interpret this error. Do I need to set an environmental variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that my problem can be remedied by upgrading mysql. I had been version 5.0, but after upgrading to version 5.5, my problem went away. Details remain unknown.